# How to configure mod_dbd with MySQL on Apache 2.2

Tags: mysql, authentication, configuration, apache2

I find it a bit strange that it is so difficult to find information about how to do this.

I want to configure my Apache2 to use mod_dbd when authenticating users. But I cannot find any examples or good descriptions anywhere about how to do this. How can I configure mod_dbd on my Apache-httpd installation?

I am using OsX and Apache 2.2. I hope there is a way to do this which is the same for both OsX and other Linux version.

I have asked this before wihtout any good answers. I assume it must be possible to do without any difficult recompiling of the Apache, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache documentation for this module contains an example that seems pretty clear - is that enough?

I don't use it because of the limitations of the password hashing which make it incompatible with many existing user databases such as those used for Dovecot IMAP. NB: Dovecot can use other hashing for passwords but requires a somewhat odd format for the password which makes life rather complex. So I use the older mod-auth-mysql